# サイトコアのブラウザ、モジュール、Azureなどの互換性をしめす情報はどこにありますか？

Tags: sitecore

*サイトコアの開発者です。[本家のスタック・オーバーフロー](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sitecore)では過去二年間でサイトコアに関する質問が３０００も超えています。日本語のスタック・オーバーフローでサイトコアの開発者と交流し、サイトコアに関した質問を今後展開したいので、この機に質問を作成させていただき、サイトコアに関したタグを作成させていただきます。

サイトコアの開発する際によく、使用するバージョンがブラウザ、モジュール、Azureなどの互換性を事前確認をすることが必要です。多くの互換性テープルはサイトコアから今年作成されたもので、ここにてよく知られている一覧をリストします。もし、漏れているものがあれば、ぜひ教えてください。

- サイトコアの互換性テーブル（[Sitecore Compatibility Table](https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/087164)）
- ASP.NET MVC 互換性テーブル（[ASP.NET MVC Compatibility Table](https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/522918)）
- サイトコアモジュールの互換性テーブル（[Sitecore Modules Compatibility Table](https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/541788)）
- サイトコアCommerce の互換性テーブル（[Sitecore Commerce Compatibility Table](https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/316437)）
- サイトコアAzure の互換性テーブル（[Sitecore Azure Compatibility Table](https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/880886)）

Comment: とりあえず、固有名詞かつ本家SOでの実績があるようなので、タグは `sitecore` にまとめたほうがいいかと http://meta.ja.stackoverflow.com/a/1385/8000

Comment: アドバイス、ありがとうございます。英語を使用します。カタカナのバージョンを削除しました。